# C# error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property line 12

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public float maxSpeed = 6.0f;
    public  bool FacingRight = true;
    public float moveDirection;

    // Use this for initialization
    void FixedUpdate () {
        Rigidbody.velocity=newVector2(moveDirection*maxSpeed,Rigidbody.velocity.y);
     /**the error is in this line this is a simple game where the player just move left and right
        where when the D +ve number  is clicked the player moves forward (right) **/
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        moveDirection = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take your RigidBody Component from your game object in order to use it. Change your fixedUpdate function with this :

```
 void FixedUpdate () 
 { 
      RigidBody rigidbody = gameObject.GetComponent<RigidBody>();
      rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection*maxSpeed,rigidbody.velocity.y);
 }
```

Comment: gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector2(moveDirection*maxSpeed,GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y); 
                                                                                                                   thanks u helped me thanks i know still beginner it worked like this